# show first item on dropdownlist with vba without cell selection

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, vba

When creating a dropdownlist from the Data => Data Validation, Excel always shows the first item on the list.

However, creating the dropdownlist in vba, the cell seems empty, only when clicking on it, the user understands that there is a dropdown list.

Is there a possibility to let excel display the first item already e.g. "choose from dropdown" so that the user understands that there is a dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub DVSetup()
    With ActiveCell.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="choose from drop down,alpha,beta,gamma,delta"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    ActiveCell.Value = "choose from drop down"
End Sub
```